# array is not getting the value in the loop

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class S1 {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        String twoDm[][]= new String[3][3];
        int i,j;

      int[] c=new int[2];
      //int []d =new int[1];

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      for(i=0;i<3;i++){
          for(j=0;j<3;j++){
              twoDm[i][j]=sc.next();
             String x= twoDm[i][j];
              if(x=="aa"){
                  c[0]=i;//values here are not getting into array c//
                  c[1]=j;

              }

      for(int f:c){
              System.out.println(f);      

          }
      }
```

The array C while printing shows 00 why are the values of i and j not getting into array what can be the problem

Comment: What are you trying to do here? What problem is this code trying to solve?

Comment: i want to get index of the array eg if i provid "e" so the i and j are index of e...trying to get that index

Answer (score 9):

`x` is a String.  You can't use `==` to test equality on Strings.

You want to use `x.equals("aa")` instead.  In case that `x` is null, you could use `"aa".equals(x)` instead (this form won't give you a NullPointerException).

Comment: I usually use `"aa".equals(x)` to avoid `NullPointerException`

Comment: @BobWang:  Yes, that's definitely the preferred style.  I'll add that in.  Although, depending on what they're doing, it might be beneficial to learn that `x` is null.

Answer (score 1):

Change your **if statement** to this:

```
if("aa".equals(x){
     c[0]=i;//values here are not getting into array c//
     c[1]=j;
}
```

Use the `String.equals(other String)` function to compare strings, not the `==` operator.

The function checks the actual contents of the string, the `==` operator checks whether the references to the objects are equal.

hope it helps..